# Can not login and register in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, sign

After I create two form(login.blade.php and register.blade.php) in views/auth folder and in route:

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

I can go to form login and  register with **http://localhost/crud/public/auth/login** **http://localhost/crud/public/auth/register**
But after I fill out the form and press **Register** this error occurred:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /auth/register was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Where can I find the controller for this or I need to implement some codes to my own controller?
Many Thanks

Comment: What does your htaccess look like? The default .htaccess is set up to account for the public folder being the webroot. You might need to set a `RewriteBase`.

Comment: my .htaccess  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: file index and htaccess is in public folder