# Why i can not register and login in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have faced a problem with Laravel 5.2 login and register.I used here Laravel 5.2 default `login.blade.php` and `register.blade.php`.All things going well but when i trying to register any user and fill up the form and submit then it do not insert any data in database and same page show in the browser window.Browser did not showed any error though i have made debug `true`.

Here is my **routes.php:**

```
<?php

use App\Member;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you will register all of the routes in an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});



Route::get('/home', function () {
   return view('home');
});

Route::get('/members', 'MemberController@index');
Route::post('/member', 'MemberController@store');
Route::delete('/member/{member}', 'MemberController@destroy');

// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
// Registration Routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    //
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

I have read many question in Stackoverflow.But all are failed to solve my problem.Here is some link of those questions:

- [Can not login and register in laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31529087/can-not-login-and-register-in-laravel-5-1)
- [Laravel 5.2 /login & /register not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749905/laravel-5-2-login-register-not-working)
- [Laravel 5.2 Authentication - How can I show logged in user's name and the logout link in every page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468455/laravel-5-2-authentication-how-can-i-show-logged-in-users-name-and-the-logout)

For find solution if you need any files then please let me know.Then i will provide here.

Comment: Shouldn't your protected routes be listed within a route group with a middleware applied to it? Unless you're doing it in the controller?

Comment: @haakym I was done in controller.Can you tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've read the answer, you're just not applying it correctly. Auth requires sessions. Any route that needs session information should be inside the `web` middleware group.

Right now, your `member`, `members`, `auth/login`, `auth/logout`, `auth/register`, 'home', and `/` routes are all outside of the `web` middleware group, so none of them will have session information available (meaning none of them will show users as logged in).

Comment: I was doing same routes for my another login and register routes and its working for me.But here when i try to register then it shows same register page and do not insert data in database without through any error.